# 1 line boolean functions python

Tags: python, function, boolean

What I've tried:

```
def is_this_5(x):
  return [True for i in range(0, 1) if x == 5]
```

However, this returns [True] and even if that could be fixed I'm sure it could be better than what I've got anyways.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what made you think you needed a list comprehension? Is there more to your problem that we do not know?

Answer (score 7):

You can just do

```
def is_this_5(x):
    return x == 5
```

as I assume you are trying to return a boolean, and `==` returns a boolean result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lambda:

```
In [4]: is_five = lambda(x): x == 5

In [5]: is_five(5)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: is_five(6)
Out[6]: False
```